# SUMIF function: sum if cell contain specific name

Tags: excel, function

I would like to run a function in Excel 2010 which has to:

- check which cell in a specific range contains a name
- if the previous task is true, sum the adjacent cell

Example:

In range B2:B227 there are some names, like Acura, Audi, BMW, Cadillac, etc.
In range C2:C227 there are the number of cars those manufactures sold in 2012.

I want to calculate the sum of cars sold by certain manufacturers.

I was thinking about something similar, but it doesn't work. I think I made a mistake on the first step (recognize the names in cell B2:B227).

`=SUMIF(B2:B227,OR("Audi","Acura","BMW","Cadillac"),D2:D227)`

Thank you,

Gianluca

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You **can** use SUMIF but as the result is an array (one sum for each criterion) you need to use SUM or SUMPRODUCT around the SUMIF to get the total, e.g.

`=SUM(SUMIF(B2:B227,{"Audi","Acura","BMW","Cadillac"},D2:D227))`

or list Audi, Acura etc in a range of cells e.g. K2:K5 and use this version

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(B2:B227,K2:K5,D2:D227))`

Answer (score 0):

I originally looked at something like the below link, but I dont think this allows you to `SUMIF` based on criteria.

[If cell contains 1 or more keywords, change value of a different cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394063/excel-if-cell-contains-1-or-more-keywords-change-value-of-a-different-cell)

---

It would appear you can longer use the `SUMIF` for multiple criteria [according to this article](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/sum-if.htm).

Ok, so if we need to sum a range of cells where corresponding cells (on the same row) meet 2, or more conditions we can no longer use the SUMIF. The formulas we can use, in order of their efficiency, are

1. DSUM Download advanced examples of DSUM
2. SUMPRODUCT
3. SUM with and IF function nested and entered as an array formula. See Array Formulas for details

For more on the different options available, [this article should be very helpful](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/sum-if.htm)

Answer (score -3):

```
=(SUMIF(A5:A230,K5:K15,C5:C230))
```

Comment: This is not only wrong, but wouldn't add anything new to this question, if it were.